# exe file exits, nasm program working fine

Tags: gcc, assembly, nasm

I've got problem, 
I can compile these programs:

- assembly program

  ```
  ;WZOR NA PI: 4 (1 - 1/3 + 1/5 - 1/7 + 1/9...)

  section .text use32

      global  _liczbae

      _liczbae:

      ; WZOR: e = 1 + (1^2/2!) + (1^3/3!) + (1^4/4!) + ...

      ; po wykonaniu push ebp i mov ebp, esp:
      ; [ebp]    old EBP location
      ; [ebp+4]  return point from procedure
      ; [ebp+8]  the first parameter of the procedure,
      ; [ebp+12] the second parameter of the procedure

      push    ebp
  mov ebp, esp ; ramka stosu

      finit   ; inicjalizacja FPU

  fild dword [ebp+8] ;  ładujemy int n do st0

  ftst        ; sprawdzamy czy n == 0
  fstsw ax    ; zapisujemy stan FPU do AX
  sahf        ; wrzucamy rejestr AH do rejestru flag
  fstp dword [n]      ; zapisujemy st0 pod adresem [n] i zrzucamy st0 ze stosu
  je koniec   ; jezeli rozne to petla

      fld1   ; ładujemy 1.0f do st0 - silnia
  fld dword [podstawa]  ; ładujemy wynik do st0 //
  fld1   ; ładujemy  temp do st0 //

  petla:
  ; st2 = silnia - 1
  ; st1 = wynik - 1
  ; st0 = temp - 1

  fld1    ; ładujemy 1.0f na stos
  faddp st3, st0  ; st3 = st3 + st0 i st0 zdejmujemy ze stosu (++silnia)

  fdiv st0, st2 ; temp = temp/silnia

  fadd st1, st0; wynik += temp

  fld dword [n]       ; ładujemy wartość n na st0
  fld1            ; ładujemy 1.0f do st0
  fsubp           ; st1 = st1 - st0 i st0 zdejmujemy ze stosu // n--;

  ftst        ; sprawdzamy czy st0 (n--) jest równe 0
  fstsw ax    ; zapisujemy stan FPU do AX
  sahf        ; wrzucamy rejestr AH do rejestru flag
  fstp dword [n]      ; zapisujemy st0 pod adresem [n] i zrzucamy st0 ze stosu
  jne petla   ; jezeli rozne to petla

  fxch st0, st1 ; wymieniamy st0 z st1 // temp = wynik, wynik = temp

      koniec:
  fld1           ; ładujemy wartośc 1.0f do st0
  faddp st1, st0 ; wynik += 1.0f == wynik += x^0/0! lub gdy x == 0.0f to e^0 == 1.0f
                 ; poprzednia linijka dodatkowo zdejmuje wartość st0 ze stosu
  leave          ; usuwa ramke stosu
  ret            ; wartosc zwracana to wartosc z rejestru st0
  n:      dd  0.0
  podstawa: dd 1.0
  ```

I named file `p4.asm`
 - c program:

```
#include <stdio.h>


extern float liczbae(int n);

int main()
{
    int n = 6;

        float wynik;
    int wait = 0;
    printf("Program liczy wartosc e z podana dokladnoscia");
        printf("\n\nPodaj dokladnosc: ");
    scanf("%d", &n);
        wynik = liczbae(n);
        printf("\ne = %f", wynik);
                scanf("%d", &wait);
    return 0;
}
```

I named file `p2.c`

now in `nasm` i can compile it with Borland with following lines:

```
cd C:\Users\jaa\Desktop\assembler projekt 2    
nasm p4.asm -f obj -o obj.obj
set path=C:\Borland\BCC55\Bin;%path%
bcc32 p2.c obj.obj
p2
```

but, when i compile using `gcc`, with following lines:

```
cd C:\Users\jaa\Desktop\assembler projekt 2
nasm -f coff p4.asm -o plik.o
set path=%pah%;C:\mingw\bin
gcc  p2.c -c -o plik1.o
gcc plik.o plik1.o -o plik.exe
```

`plik.exe` runs, but it crashes when i type `11` and `enter` but that error doesn't occur in nasm. I wonder why?

Comment: Please format your posts properly in the future. If they're not readable, noone will be able or willing to help you. It seems you got confused too - the two shell snippets are exactly the same.

Comment: thank you, i tried, but i couldn;t do it as you, thanks !

Comment: check http://stackoverflow.com/editing-help for the details.

Comment: Nasm's `-f coff` output format is for DJGPP. `-f win32` should work better with MinGW. Not clear whether that's your problem or not. (hint: for Borland, assembling with `-f win32` and converting the object file to OMF with Agner Fog's "objconv" may work better - Nasm's `-f obj` 32-bit extensions don't play nicely with Borland)

Comment: but with borland it works great ! And with 'gcc' ( that is from MinGw) .exe crasheh while in use ;o

Comment: I see you resurrected your own question after a number of years with some edits. Were you still looking for an answer?

Comment: After years of experience I formatted it better to make it more readable.

Answer (score 1):

As Frank pointed out, the format for NASM with MingW-GCC should be `-f win32`.

I'm surprised that it works with BCC32 (version here: 5.8.2). There is a variable in the .text section that is accessed for writing by `fstp dword [n]`. The .text section should not be writeable.

Insert the line

```
section .data use32 class=DATA
```

after `ret` and

change

```
section .text use32
```

to

```
section .text use32 class=CODE
```